# ASP.NET: how to handle events arising from controls in popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net

have a popup window in which there is a button whose clicks I would like to handle in code behind. When I attempt to double click in designer to access the event, Visual Studio does not allow me to access events. I realize that this popup window is from telerik and therefore foreign to many but I believe that it should behave the same as a regular popup window in this respect.

```
  <telerik:RadWindow ID="NewSNPPopup" runat="server" Height="400px" Modal="true" Width="825px">
                    <ContentTemplate>                        
                         <asp:Button Style="margin-left: 25px;" ID="pmModalSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Visible="True" />                               
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </telerik:RadWindow>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the Telerik site has many examples for this have you checked out this site [Telerik](http://docs.telerik.com/) || [Telerik Support](http://www.telerik.com/support)

Comment: yeah I am aware of their website.

Comment: well check it out then ..there are also many examples of how to do this on line it doesn't appear that you have really tried anything on your own besides posting some very minor code.. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx#qsf-demo-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used designer in ages. Anyhow, double click works for me. When I double click on a button, it creates click event inside code behind.

[image]

Make sure you register telerik inside page.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" 
     Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
```

Or I normally place it inside web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" 
           assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```